# Sed - How to match a regex group and use it to replace all other matched occurrences in the same line?

Tags: sed

I'm trying to repeat a matched pattern n times in the same line, depending on another match (Constant).

**Input**

```
Parent:X 4541, SomeData, Constant:Child: Variable1, SomeData, Constant:Child: Variable2, SomeData, Constant:Child: Variable3, SomeData, 
Parent:Y 2131, SomeData, Constant:Child: Variable4, SomeData, Constant:Child: Variable5, SomeData, Constant:Child: Variable6, SomeData, 
Parent:Z 51 F, SomeData, Constant:Child: Variable7, SomeData, Constant:Child: Variable8, SomeData, Constant:Child: Variable9, SomeData,
```

**Expected output**

```
Parent:X 4541, SomeData, X 4541: Child: Variable1, SomeData, X 4541: Child: Variable2, SomeData, X 4541: Child: Variable3, SomeData, 
Parent:Y 2131, SomeData, Y 2131: Child: Variable4, SomeData, Y 2131: Child: Variable5, SomeData, Y 2131: Child: Variable6, SomeData, 
Parent:Z 51 F, SomeData, Z 51 F: Child: Variable7, SomeData, Z 51 F: Child: Variable8, SomeData, Z 51 F: Child: Variable9, SomeData,
```

Note that I replaced every `Constant` with `Parent`'s name.

I think `sed` hold space might be the answer, but I honestly couldn't do it.

If it helps solving the problem, I can break the lines before every `Constant` first:

```
Parent:X 4541, SomeData, 
Constant:Child: Variable1, SomeData, 
Constant:Child: Variable2, SomeData, 
Constant:Child: Variable3, SomeData, 
Parent:Y 2131, SomeData, 
Constant:Child: Variable4, SomeData, 
Constant:Child: Variable5, SomeData, 
Constant:Child: Variable6, SomeData, 
Parent:Z 51 F, SomeData, 
Constant:Child: Variable7, SomeData, 
Constant:Child: Variable8, SomeData, 
Constant:Child: Variable9, SomeData,
```

and it doesn't matter if the **output** isn't in the same line:

```
Parent:X 4541, SomeData, 
 X 4541: Child: Variable1, SomeData, 
 X 4541: Child: Variable2, SomeData, 
 X 4541: Child: Variable3, SomeData, 
Parent:Y 2131, SomeData, 
 Y 2131: Child: Variable4, SomeData, 
 Y 2131: Child: Variable5, SomeData, 
 Y 2131: Child: Variable6, SomeData, 
Parent:Z 51 F, SomeData, 
 Z 51 F: Child: Variable7, SomeData, 
 Z 51 F: Child: Variable8, SomeData, 
 Z 51 F: Child: Variable9, SomeData,
```

Efforts:

This will correctly replace the last `Constant` with the a line break followed by `parent`'s name, but I've to repeat the command multiple times untill there is no match left (Not practical).

```
Sed -r -i "s#Parent:([^,]*)(.*)Constant:#\1\2\n\1: #" file
```

Using `awk` is fine, but it would be much appreciated if anyone can help with a `sed` command with some explanation.

Comment: Please add your attempted code

Comment: @anubhava As I said bro, I couldn't do it. The only way that worked is complicated and it's not practical if the file is big. I had to split every line in separate files, and break the lines in each file before the "constant" then I used this:
    `For /R "separatefiles\" %%A in ("*.txt") Do ( FOR /F "tokens=* usebackq" %%G in (`sed -r "s#Parent:([^,]*).*#\1#"`) Do ( Sed -i "s/Constant:/%%G: /" "%%A" )
)`

Comment: @anubhava There's also another way to do it in the same file using sed, but still not practical in any way. I can make a greedy match from Parent to Constant, and replace it with a line break: `Sed -r -i "s#Parent:([^,]*)(.*)Constant:#\1\2\n\1: #" file`
and of course I've to repeat the command untill there's no match left

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `sed` based on the code from your comment:

```
sed -E ':a;s/(Parent:([^,]*).*)Constant:/\1\2: /;t a' file
```

`t` is for "test". If a previous `s///` was successful, it goes to the specified label, or to the end of the script.

Comment: For branching in sed see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Branching-and-flow-control) or [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Branching-and-Cycles).

Answer (score 2):

Another `awk` solution:

```sh
awk -F '[,:]+' '{gsub(/ Constant:/, " " $2 ": ")} 1' file

Parent:X 4541, SomeData, X 4541: Child: Variable1, SomeData, X 4541: Child: Variable2, SomeData, X 4541: Child: Variable3, SomeData,
Parent:Y 2131, SomeData, Y 2131: Child: Variable4, SomeData, Y 2131: Child: Variable5, SomeData, Y 2131: Child: Variable6, SomeData,
Parent:Z 51 F, SomeData, Z 51 F: Child: Variable7, SomeData, Z 51 F: Child: Variable8, SomeData, Z 51 F: Child: Variable9, SomeData,
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "} {split($1,arr,":");gsub(/Constant:/,arr[2]": ")} 1' Input_file
```

To perform inplace saving run following code.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "} {split($1,arr,":");gsub(/Constant:/,arr[2]": ")} 1' Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file
```